# umlaut in wp7 webbrowser displayed incorrectly

Tags: windows-phone-7, browser, webbrowser-control

I have an issue with WebBrowser content at windows phone 7.
Need to display multy-language web content in my app. Such pages has encoding="utf-8.
Umlauts displayed as another symbols instesd of Å,å,Ä,ä,Ö,ö.
The same page displayed well in opera, chrome ff and ie.

Great thanks in advance.

Comment: The proper markup for umlauts, eg. &uuml; is used in your web content?

Comment: can you provide a repro? I'd suspect that it's due to the file being saved with the wrong encoding.

Answer (score 1):

Try this extension method

```
public static class StringExtensionMethods
{
    public static string ToExtendedASCII(this string html)
    {
        string retVal = "";
        char[] s = html.ToCharArray();

        foreach (char c in s)
        {
            if (Convert.ToInt32(c) > 127)
                retVal += "&#" + Convert.ToInt32(c) + ";";
            else
                retVal += c;
        }
        return retVal;
    }
}
```